# How can i use accepts nested attributes with the HABTM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models User and Category.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
    end
```

similarly

```
    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    end
```

i have a requirement where i have to add the categories to the categories table and add the reference so that i can get the categories related to user but if another user enters the same category then i have to make use of the id instead of creating new one. How can i do it?

And one more thing is i have to add an attribute type which refers that category type. for example

```
user1 ----> category1, category2
user2 ----> category2
```

here user1 and user2 has category2 but the type in category2 may differ.So how can i maintain this? please help me. I am ready to answer your question.

Comment: Category `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` not `categories`, right? Also, what you want to do with this `type`. I don't get it....

Comment: Thanks. I have changed and i need to have type field which says the user has category2 with type "type1" and user2 has same category2 with type "type2". where should i keep the type field. If i have type field in join table how can i add the entry and get that information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use `has_many :through` instead of `HABTM` to add the field `type` to the relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines
  has_many :categories, through: :lines
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
  has_many :users, through: :lines
end
```

Add the `type` attribute to the class `Line`.

ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

You will need two controllers with the restful actions: `users` and `categories`

Then, in your user form, something like:

```
<%= nested_form_for @user do |f| %>
...#user attributes
<%= f.fields_for :lines do |line| %>
<%= line.label :category %>
<%= line.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name , {include_blank: 'Select Category'} ) %>
<%= line.label :type %>
<%= line.text_field :type %>
...#the form continues
```

EDIT -

The category is independent of user, as well as user is independent of category.

The association class `Line` will join users and categories through the `category_id` and `user_id`:

```
________          _______________
| user |          |     line    |          ____________
|----- |          |-------------|          | category |
| id   |----------| user_id     |          |----------|
| name |1        *| category_id |----------| id       |
| email|          | type        |*        1| name     | 
|______|          |_____________|          |__________|
```

example:

git hub: https://github.com/gabrielhilal/nested_form

heroku: http://nestedform.herokuapp.com/

Comment: If i use accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines then how would the category information be stored in category table. It is bit unclear for me. Could you please explain more.

Comment: Also tell me if another user enters a new value to categories it should check if the category is present already and it should just add the id of the category along with type.

Comment: It took some time for me to understand. Anyway thank you and one small correction which is the join table model should have belongs_to :user and belongs_to :category.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, but the code is right in the repository I gave u: https://github.com/gabrielhilal/nested_form/blob/master/app/models/line.rb please accept the answer if it answered your question.